# Gzipping and setting expires headers on Google Cloud Storage

Tags: gzip, google-cloud-storage, gsutil, expires-header

I'm using the following commands to upload files to Google's Cloud Storage. These commands gzip HTML, CSS and JS and then set expires headers to 6 months on CSS, JS and images.

```
gsutil -m cp -z "html,css,js" -r dist/** gs://bucket/
gsutil -m setmeta -h "Cache-Control: public, max-age=15552000" gs://bucket/**/*.css
gsutil -m setmeta -h "Cache-Control: public, max-age=15552000" gs://bucket/**/*.js
gsutil -m setmeta -h "Cache-Control: public, max-age=15552000" gs://bucket/**/*.gif
gsutil -m setmeta -h "Cache-Control: public, max-age=15552000" gs://bucket/**/*.png
gsutil -m setmeta -h "Cache-Control: public, max-age=15552000" gs://bucket/**/*.jpg
```

Is it possible to simplify this to one or two commands?

Answer (score 0):

The cp command accepts -h arguments for valid metadata.  So you should be able to do:

`gsutil -m -h "Cache-Control: public, max-age=15552000" cp -z "html,css,js" -r dist/** gs://bucket/`

Note that the -h comes prior to the cp command.

Comment: I ended up using the following since I don't want far future expires headers set on my HTML and images. https://gist.github.com/mraible/0cca15e8340135121f9b

Comment: Ah, sorry I missed that you wanted to apply the headers in a mixed-mode.  Your code looks good.